# How to find average of column and append it for multiple columns in a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I have a dataset that has 100 school names, three academic years, and 60 indicators. I need to get the average for each indicator for each school for each year. So for 1 indicator, I will have 300 different averages. I need that average appended to the dataset. I know how to do this. The issue is, I want to do it for all 60 indicators in one loop. So I have 60 new columns in the dataset.

```
df <- df %>f%
  group_by(School, Year) %>% 
  mutate(Indicator1_average = mean(Indicator1, na.rm=T)
```

Here would  be how I would do it for one indicator. How do I create a loop to do this for all 60?

Edit: WITH SOME OUTPUT

```
School          Year                Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3
1 LAKE Park     2021-2022            NA             4            NA
2 LAKE Park     2021-2022            NA             1            NA
3 LAKE Park     2021-2022             2             1             1
4 LAKE Park     2021-2022            NA            NA            NA
5 LAKE Park     2021-2022            NA             1             1
```

Comment: the 100 school names, are they 100 variables or just one variable?

Comment: There are 100 schools in the dataset

Comment: like 100 columns or just 1 column?

Comment: just 1 column with all of them listed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 df %>f%
  group_by(School, Year) %>% 
  mutate(across(contains('Indicator'), mean, na.rm = TRUE, .names = '{col}_Indicator'))
```

Comment: I am getting an error Error in `mutate_cols()`:
! Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = across(contains("Indicator"), mean, .names = "{.col}_average")`.
x Problem with `across()` input `.fns`.
i `.fns` must be NULL, a function, a formula, or a list of functions/formulas.
Caused by error in `across_setup()`:
! Problem with `across()` input `.fns`.
i `.fns` must be NULL, a function, a formula, or a list of functions/formulas.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred

Comment: @vp2019 what code are you trying to run?

Comment: clean <- clean %>%
  group_by(School, Year) %>%
  mutate(across(contains('Indicator'), mean, na.rm = TRUE, .names = "{.col}_average"))

Comment: changed the name slightly then what you had

Comment: @vp2019 can you paste the output of `clean[1:5, 1:5]` in your question

Comment: added to the question

Comment: okay its working now BUT i am get NaN for all the averages in the new columns